# Send variable to Simulink by set_param

Tags: matlab, simulink

If I want to send a `Constant Block`, a value from a `Matlab` file. It only accepts:

```
set_param('myModel/Constant','Value', '150')
```

I need to replace `150` with variable `x` to be like:

```
set_param('myModel/Constant','Value', x)
```

but it didn't respond. I tried 'UserDefined' rather than 'Constant' but it didn't either.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just like you did with '150', you set the Value param as a string.

```
set_param('myModel/Constant','Value', 'x')
```

Note the quotes around 'x'. Unless x is already a string holding another variable's name you use quotes around the value.

Comment: I tried it, it passed the X as string rather than the value where the X contains

x=6;
set_param('myModel/Constant','Value', 'x');

It wont pass 6, it will pass x as string

Any help ?

Comment: Passing `'x'` as a string is the right way to parameterize your model.  Then you just change the value of `x` in the MATLAB Workspace and Simulink will use that value.  If you insist on putting an actual number into the model then use `set_param(...,...,num2str(x))`